# Python Uploading on webbrowser

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, python-webbrowser

I am writing an script that will upload file from my local machine to an webpage. This is the url: `https://tutorshelping.com/bulkask` and there is a upload option. but i am trouble not getting how to upload it.

my current script:

```
import webbrowser, os

def fileUploader(dirname):
    mydir = os.getcwd() + dirname
    filelist = os.listdir(mydir)
    for file in filelist:
        filepath = mydir + file #This is the file absolte file path
        print(filepath)

    url = "https://tutorshelping.com/bulkask"
    webbrowser.open_new(url)  # open in default browser
    webbrowser.get('firefox').open_new_tab(url)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    dirname = '/testdir'
    fileUploader(dirname)
```

Comment: maybe something here: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12851/how-can-i-work-with-file-uploads-during-a-webdriver-test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick solution would be to use something like AppRobotic personal macro software to either interact with the Windows pop-ups and apps directly, or just use X,Y coordinates to move the mouse, click on buttons, and then to send keyboard keys to type or tab through your files.

Something like this would work when tweaked, so that it runs at the point when you're ready to click the upload button and browse for your file:

```
import win32com.client
x = win32com.client.Dispatch("AppRobotic.API")
import webbrowser

# specify URL
url = "https://www.google.com"

# open with default browser
webbrowser.open_new(url) 

# wait a bit for page to open
x.Wait(3000)
# use UI Item Explorer to find the X,Y coordinates of Search box
x.MoveCursor(438, 435)
# click inside Search box
x.MouseLeftClick

x.Type("AppRobotic")
x.Type("{ENTER}")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the Python webbrowser package can do anything else than open a browser / tab with a specific url.

If I understand your question well, you want to open the page, set the file to upload and then simulate a button click. You can try [pyppeteer](https://pypi.org/project/pyppeteer/) for this.

*Disclaimer: I have never used the Python version, only the JS version (puppeteer).*